# Prove that the number $P(n)-P(n-1)$ is equal number of divisions $n$ for ingredients larger than $1$

Tags: combinatorics

> Prove that the number $P(n)-P(n-1)$ is equal number of divisions $n$ for ingredients larger than $1$. $P(n)$  is number of possible divisions of $n$.

**My solution:**

We want to show that $P(n-1)$ is a number of divisions $n$ for ingredients among which is $1$.

$ \bullet \bullet \bullet \bullet \bullet $ 
$ \bullet \bullet \bullet \bullet $ 
$ \bullet \bullet \bullet $ 
$ \bullet \bullet $ 
$ \bullet $ 
$ \bullet $

To this end, we will show a bid between the $n$ split into ingredients from $ 1 $ and any $n-1$ split:

$ \bullet \bullet \bullet \bullet \bullet $ 
$ \bullet \bullet \bullet \bullet \bullet $ 
$ \bullet \bullet \bullet \bullet $ 
$ \bullet \bullet \bullet $ 
$ \bullet \bullet \bullet $ 
$ \bullet \bullet $ 
$ \bullet \bullet $ 
And we add $1$:
$ \bullet \bullet \bullet \bullet \bullet $ 
$ \bullet \bullet \bullet \bullet \bullet $ 
$ \bullet \bullet \bullet \bullet $ 
$ \bullet \bullet \bullet $ 
$ \bullet \bullet \bullet $ 
$ \bullet \bullet $ 
$ \bullet \bullet $ 
$ \bullet $ 
We see that after adding we have the same plus $1$ so it's proof.

Can you check my solution?

Comment: what is $P(n)$?

Comment: You should first define clearly your notation...

Comment: @Aqua I'm really sorry I forgot to write it, I edited my post

Comment: One problem with your proof is that it applies to a specific $n$ ($4$ or $5$ by the looks of it) ... how do we know that it generalizes to *any* $n$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Ferrers_diagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume $P(n)$ denotes the number of partitions of $n$.

Saying that
$P(n)-P(n-1)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ with parts all of size $\ge2$
is the same as saying that $P(n-1)$ is the number of partitions of $n$
having $1$ as a part. But those partitions are got by appending a part $1$ to the
partitions of $n-1$.